# how to select from temporary table within store procedure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mariadb, procedure

I've a SP in MySQL ( Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB - Source distribution )
SP creates a temporary table :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY table actions
SELECT a.Name as name
from Campaign as c 
INNER join Action as a 
on c.Action_Ref = a.Id
GROUP by a.Name;
```

then I want to select some data from this temp table , when I add this line :

```
SELECT * from actions;
```

I'll get error:

> One or more errors have occurred while processing your request: The
> following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
> PROCEDURE `ActionsOfCampaign` ... at line 11

I know that I can do this

```
CALL ActionsOfCampaign();
SELECT * from actions;
```

but I insist on doing the select part within the  procedure .
thank you for your answers in advanced

Comment: I would ask why do you need to create the temporary table in the first place? Other than the select statement you shown there is no use for it.

Comment: I have another table in DB , I'll join temp table to that another table and then I group by in merged data .

Comment: Why not show the full stored procedrue you are trying to create. Did you change the `DELIMITER`?

Comment: @slaakso i'm using phpmyadmin so i don't  have to change delimiter . btw I'm showing the complete sp , there is no more :)

Comment: @cchajar phpmyadmin uses delimiter also and it is by default `;` which would cause an error when creating a procedure with multiople queries. And you do not show the full code for your procedure, just two separate queries. It would be easier to help if you show the full procedure code.